# mysql script to t-sql script

Tags: mysql, t-sql, converters

I work with Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

I received a big .sql file which contains CREATE TABLE statements for about 150 tables and the INSERT INTO statements with corresponding data for these tables. Unfortunately the script does not run because it is (I think) mysql script and not t-sql script.

Smart search and replace is not sufficient and rewriting takes to much time for all 150 tables. I tried to find software that converts mysql script to tsql script but could not find anything that does the job.

What would be a smart way to proceed? Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please provide more information? What exactly the error is ?  assuming your data is in mysql and needs to be dumped in sql   right?

Answer (score 0):

[How do I convert mySql SQL script to MS SQL one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7820626/how-do-i-convert-mysql-sql-script-to-ms-sql-one)

I would personally install MySQL (as it's always useful as a developer to have!). Run the script against a MySQL DB.

Download Navicat Premium and then using the wizard, transfer data from MySQL to MSSQL