# Importing .sql file into SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have database with `.sql`, I want to import that `.sql` file into SQL Server 2012 using Management Studio.

When I tried to import the data, I'm getting an error:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 76
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'NOT'.


[![enter image description here][1]][1]


 CREATE TABLE ct_bookings(
   id int NOT NULL,
   order_id bigint NOT NULL,
   client_id bigint NOT NULL,
   order_date date NOT NULL,
   booking_date_time datetime NOT NULL,
   service_id int NOT NULL,
   method_id int NOT NULL,
   method_unit_id int NOT NULL,
   method_unit_qty int NOT NULL,
   method_unit_qty_rate double NOT NULL,
   booking_status varchar(10) not null    ('A','C','R','CC','CS','CO','MN','RS') NOT NULL COMMENT 'A=active, C=confirm,   R=Reject, CC=Cancel by Client, CS=Cancel by service   provider,CO=Completed,MN=MARK AS NOSHOW',
  `reject_reason` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `reminder_status` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0=Email Not    Sent,1=Email Sent',
  `lastmodify` datetime NOT NULL,
  `read_status` enum('R','U') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'U'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

How can I solve this issue?

Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are running `MySQL` script into `SQL Server` Engine. !

Comment: yes i'm importing mysql to sql server

Comment: post the particular section of code which fails

Comment: I'm importing entire database which is in gms.sql file. Not executing single query.

Comment: `SET SQL_MODE = ....` & `SET TIME_ZONE = ....` related to `MySQL`, so remove them , then show us the code that fails.

Comment: Maybe help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7820626/how-do-i-convert-mysql-sql-script-to-ms-sql-one

Comment: question edited please check it once

Comment: @user3668438 Follow My Answer.

Comment: Please don't edit the post complete in such a way that the present answers are invalidated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `MySQL`:-

```
CREATE TABLE ct_addon_service_rate(
  id int(11) NOT NULL,
  addon_service_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  unit varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  rules VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL CHECK (rules IN('E', 'G')),
  rate DOUBLE NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Equals in `SQL Server`:-

```
Create TABLE ct_addon_service_rate (
  id int NOT NULL,
  addon_service_id int NOT NULL,
  unit varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  rules char(1) not null,
  rate FLOAT(25) NOT NULL,
  CHECK (rules in ('E', 'G'))
)
```

### Update:-

In `MySQL`:-

```
CREATE TABLE ct_bookings(
   id int NOT NULL,
   order_id bigint NOT NULL,
   client_id bigint NOT NULL,
   order_date date NOT NULL,
   booking_date_time datetime NOT NULL,
   service_id int NOT NULL,
   method_id int NOT NULL,
   method_unit_id int NOT NULL,
   method_unit_qty int NOT NULL,
   method_unit_qty_rate double NOT NULL,
   booking_status varchar(10) not null    ('A','C','R','CC','CS','CO','MN','RS') NOT NULL COMMENT 'A=active, C=confirm,   R=Reject, CC=Cancel by Client, CS=Cancel by service   provider,CO=Completed,MN=MARK AS NOSHOW',
  `reject_reason` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `reminder_status` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0=Email Not    Sent,1=Email Sent',
  `lastmodify` datetime NOT NULL,
  `read_status` enum('R','U') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'U'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Equals in `SQL Server`:-

```
CREATE TABLE ct_bookings(
   id int NOT NULL,
   order_id bigint NOT NULL,
   client_id bigint NOT NULL,
   order_date date NOT NULL,
   booking_date_time datetime NOT NULL,
   service_id int NOT NULL,
   method_id int NOT NULL,
   method_unit_id int NOT NULL,
   method_unit_qty int NOT NULL,
   method_unit_qty_rate float(25) NOT NULL,
   booking_status varchar(10) not null  check  (booking_status in ('A','C','R','CC','CS','CO','MN','RS')),
    /*COMMENT 'A=active, C=confirm,   R=Reject, CC=Cancel by Client, CS=Cancel by service   provider,CO=Completed,MN=MARK AS NOSHOW', */
  reject_reason varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  reminder_status char(1)NOT NULL check (reminder_status in ('0','1'))  DEFAULT '0', /*COMMENT '0=Email Not    Sent,1=Email Sent', */
  lastmodify datetime NOT NULL,
  read_status char(1) NOT NULL check (read_status in ('R','U')) DEFAULT 'U'
)
```

### Update 2:-

in `MySQL`:-

```
CREATE TABLE ct_email_templates (
  id int NOT NULL,
  email_subject varchar(200) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NOT NULL,
  email_message text COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NOT NULL,
  default_message text COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NOT NULL,
  email_template_status varchar(10) NOT NULL check(email_template_status in('E','D')) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS,
  email_template_type varchar(10) check(email_template_type IN('A','C','R','CC','RS','RM')) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NOT NULL COMMENT 'A=active, C=confirm, R=Reject, CC=Cancel by Client, RS=Reschedule, RM=Reminder',
  user_type` enum('A','C') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'A=Admin,C=client'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Equals in `SQL Server`:-

```
CREATE TABLE ct_email_templates (
  id int NOT NULL,
  email_subject varchar(200) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NOT NULL,
  email_message text COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NOT NULL,
  default_message text COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NOT NULL,
  email_template_status varchar(10) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NOT NULL check(email_template_status in('E','D')) ,
  email_template_type varchar(10) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS check(email_template_type IN('A','C','R','CC','RS','RM'))  NOT NULL, /*COMMENT 'A=active, C=confirm, R=Reject, CC=Cancel by Client, RS=Reschedule, RM=Reminder',
  user_type` enum('A','C') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'A=Admin,C=client' */
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, i was solved. Can you please check again the question edited.

Comment: can't we assign values here like (A=active)?

Comment: No, it is just a comment, it is usful for documentation or notes ... etc

Comment: ok, how can we write this on (email_template_status varchar(10) NOT NULL check(email_template_status in('E','D')) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS)

Comment: Show me the all entire code, and what is the error that you get !?

Comment: kindly if the issue is resolved, set the answer as accepted one.

Comment: Glad to help you.

Comment: If we don't mention int(11) length how much length it take by default?

Comment: An INT will always be 4 bytes no matter what length is specified.
According to here, int(11) will take 4 bytes of space that is 32 bits of space with  2^(31) = 2147483648 max value and -2147483648min value. One bit is for sign, fore more details: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html

Comment: How can we write this in sql server? ALTER TABLE ct_admin_info
  add id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=2;